# reslover function doesn't work for promise object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying use `Promise` in Node.js to read files, but the `return promise` got `{}`. The code is as bellow:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    var readPath = __dirname + '/users.json';

    readJSONFile(readPath).then(function(userList) {
        insertUser(userList);
        console.log("read ok", userList);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

}).listen(8888);

function readJSONFile(readPath) {

    console.log("readJSONFile called");

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(readPath, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log("json ok", data);
                resolve(json);
            }
        });
    });
console.log(promise);
return promise;
}
```

The output is

```
app-0 readJSONFile called
app-0 {}
app-0 json ok [...the json string...]
```

<del>I have no idea why the `console.log(promise)` is null.</del>

With the codes above nothing happened in the resolver function. I can get the right output with `console.log("json ok", data);` but nothing with `console.log("read ok", userList);`

My node's version is 0.12 which do support Promise.

Comment: Your second log is of the instantiated promise. That is a object that promises to have data in the future but does not at the time of the logging. It might be `{ }` or it might show some of its internal functions, but it wll not have data at this stage. To my mind, everything is fine for you at present

Comment: It works for me (node 4.1.2).  Note though (as per jfriend00's) answer that the promise object is _not_ `null`, it's just being printed as an _empty object_.  On 4.1.2 it shows as `Promise { <pending> }` - presumably on 4.1.2 there's a better `.toString` method for Promises.

Comment: @SimonH Thanks. I got that. I edited the question. My real problem is the resolver function doesn't work. Could you help with that?

Comment: OK, so the problem is probably no tPromises. I would change to `console.log("json ok", data);` and see what you get

Comment: @SimonH I can get a json string correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't `null`.  Per your output, it's just showing as an empty object.

While the `console.log()` behavior is not governed by an accepted standard, what you are seeing is probably because the promise object has no publicly enumerable properties so `console.log()` has nothing to show.  It doesn't mean the promise object is actually empty.

The better test is whether `readJSONFile(readPath).then(...)` actually works.  If so, then it is obviously a valid promise object and it was just your logging that was confused.

Comment: Thanks. I got that. I edited the question. My real problem is the resolver function doesn't work. Could you help with that?

Comment: @BrickYang - this is NOT how you're supposed to use Stack Overflow.  You should not edit your question into a different queston from what you originally asked.  I answered the question you originally asked.  If, now understanding that answer, you have a new question, you should ask a new question.

Comment: @BrickYang - There's nothing conceptually wrong with your code so there must be some sort of error in your `resolve()` path.  The most likely thing I can guess is that your JSON isn't legal JSON so `JSON.parse()` is throwing an exception which is silent because it's thrown inside an async callback.  You can put a try/catch around your `JSON.parse()` and log if there's an exception thrown there.  Another possibility is that `insertUser()` is throwing an exception.

Comment: Sorry, got that. Could I do something to fix this mistake?

Comment: You can accept this answer to your original question, revert the edit and post a new question.  I tried to help you anyway with my last comment.

Comment: yes, you are right. The problem is the `insertUser` function. I'll accept this answer. Thanks && sorry for your notice again.